# I need to try to boot several times to manage to show log in display and boot normally

Tags: boot, dual-boot, kubuntu

I'm using reFind to dual boot windows and Kubuntu. I select Kubuntu, then I get these errors:
[image: The errors I get when booting]

[image: I can move the mouse but can't click anything]

I can move the mouse but can't click anything. Then I reboot several times until I manage to get through.

This is my version of OS:

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```

I have installed the latest Nvidia drivers:

```
nvidia-smi
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001F02sv00001462sd0000C75Cbc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : TU106 [GeForce RTX 2070]
 Driver Version: 535.129.03   CUDA Version: 12.2
```

Any idea what can It be?

Comment: It looks like your disk (`/dev/sda`) is failing. Boot from a live USB and run `fsck` on it. BACKUP your system.

Comment: @waltinator thank you, while I'm backing up my os drive by creating a partition image, I got the warning 1.5 mb unreadable replaced with zeroes

Comment: I used fsck and found no errors, but then on gnome disk I did repair file system. Will monitor and check if the problem is resolved in the next couple of days

Comment: Ok it seems like the problem still persists...

Comment: I solved it by creating a partition image and then using a different drive